# How to avoid code duplication in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, code-reuse

I have an android app, in which I have side menu in almost all of my activities. For that, I have to next my activity xml with a drawer layout and some other items for a consistent UI. 
For example

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"/>

        <<--ACTIVITY_XML-->>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is there any way to not copy the code again and again.

I thought of one way, Replace `<<--ACTIVITY_XML-->>` with an include tag. Then I would override `setContentView()` in my base activity, Where i would inflate the basic layout mentioned above, and then inflate include tag inside it. Is this way good or bad in terms of memory and time utilisation.

Comment: search on include AND merge tag use both for better optimization

Comment: you can use 1 activity as a main-container with the common UI elements and the drawer, then use replace Fragment in that activity, it's a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches:

1. Override **setContentView** in your super activity class and inflate from code the instance activity layout in your root layout.
2. Use **include** tag in addition to **merge** tag for performance optimization in every activity layout.

Personally, in my app i prefer to override setContentView to insert the Toolbar in every activity, keeping one layout for each activity copying the root layout.

In your case maybe it's better to use the 'root' layout inflating custom activity xml to centralize code. But if in future for example you'll want to remove drawer for one activity, you'll have to manage that.

Comment: Could you explain 2nd approach once. 
About drawer to be not there for one activity, I created two baseActivities - baseActivity, sideBarActivity. But for a sideBarActivity also there maybe some changes in toolbar and those similar things, Do you have any solution for that

Comment: Using 2nd approach  you must copy the code for each activity, using include and merge but is not what you want looking at the question. If you already have 2 base activities sounds perfect for drawer visibility. Use first approach and you'll have 2 different root layouts with custom activity layout inflated from code. About your memory doubt, this is only a different code organization, it doesn't affect performance if code is well written